# Python: How to check user input is a value or a str?

Tags: python

how to write python code to ask user to input a number, return the int of the number, and if user input a str, for example "One", return a error message like "please input a int number"? How could I do that?

Also I have to check if the number is odd or not, so i m not sure if I can do it with try and except.I dunno how to add that in my code.

Thanks.

```
def getnum(): 

    errormessage="Please input a odd number"

    asknum=raw_input("Please input a number: ")
    num=int(asknum)

    if num%2!=0:  #return num if it is odd number
        print num

    else:
        print errormessage
        return getnum()

getnum()
```

Answer (score 6):

```
try:
    a = int(raw_input("Enter an integer: "))
    print a  # or do anything else with "a"
except ValueError:
    print "Please enter an integer."
```

---

**EDIT** In response to the [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523839/python-how-to-check-user-input-is-a-value-or-a-str/12523860#comment16859795_12523860):

```
try:
    a = int(raw_input("Enter an integer: "))
    if a % 2 == 1:
       print "Integer is odd"  # or do anything else
    else:
       print "Integer is even"  # or do anything else
except ValueError:
    print "Please enter an integer."
```

Comment: I also have to check if the number is odd or not, return the number if it is odd. but i cannot do that with try and except.

Answer (score 1):

Note that using raw_input() will store the variable as a string, if you want to store it automatically as an int, use input(). 
This is for Python versions before 3.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways you could try it.

One way is

```
userinput = raw_input()
if not all(x in string.digits for x in userinput):
     print 'Please enter an int number'
```

but that's a little weak on the verification - it just checks that all the input characters are digits.

Or you could try

```
userinput = raw_input()
try:
     asint = int(userinput)
except ValueError:
     print 'Please enter an int number'
```

but that uses try/except for something that should be a simple if/else.

Comment: Well, your first example should be redone as `userinput.isdigit()`, I think.

Comment: Yes, that's shorter, though as an aside I must say: IMHO that method is misnamed, as you would think it returns true only if the string is just one digit (for example '4') and not a sequence of digits.

Comment: Yeah, it's a hold out from C. Probably better to say 'isdigits' or something (isalpha, isalnum at least kind of make sense).

Answer (score 0):

```
s = input()
try:
    return int(s)
except:
    return 'Error'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the isdigit() function for string objects.

Returns true if number else false.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you wanted using the other answers mentioned. 
For some extra information,the type of a variable in python can be obtained by using the `type()`

```
>>> a = 1
>>> type(a)
<type 'int'>
>>> b = 'str'
<type 'str'>
```

you can check a variable's type by

```
>>> if type(a) == int:
...     print 'a is integer'
... 
a is integer
```